# Getting none in beautiful soup web-scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**My intend**

I want to **scrape** commits of user from [github](https://github.com/pnp/cli-microsoft365) using beautiful soup with python.

**My issue**

Getting `none` as result of my script.

**My code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://github.com/pnp/cli-microsoft365').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
commits = soup.select_one('svg.octicon.octicon-history + span strong').text
print(commits)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Your using a "wild mix" in your `find()` and this will not lead to the element you are expected to find, thats why you get a `None`

#### How to fix?

Use the css selector to chain the parts you are looking for, in this case it will pick the `<svg>` in front of commits and its next `<span>` element that contains the `<strong>`:

```
soup.select_one('svg.octicon.octicon-history + span strong').text
```

#### Output (in moment of my request)

```
1,664
```